# Region field is not working on country change

Tags: magento2.3, onepage-checkout, magento2.3.4, country-regions, required

I am facing an issue in magento 2.3.4.Whenever I tried to change country, region field hidden and gives required error. Therefore, Place order is not happening.  If i have not changed country and just fill other fields other fields and click on place order, Then it is working fine.

[image: Checkout page image]

Answer (score 0):

Please select "No" for "Allow to Choose State if It is Optional for Country" under below path :

1. Admin > Store > Configuration > General
2. General > State Options
3. Select "No" for "Allow to Choose State if It is Optional for Country"

Save Configuration.

It may help you to resolve issue.

Comment: I have already tried it. It's not working.

Comment: Then over ride jquery file "vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/region.js" with your theme and changes conditions according to your requirement